# Prevent permanent redirect in asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect

I wanted to redirect `abc.azurewebsites.net` to `abc.com`. For this I wrote following code in web.config:

```
 <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Disable Azure Domain" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="*.azurewebsites.net" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://abc.pk{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

The above code sucessfully redirected `abc.azurewebsites.net` to `abc.com`.

Now I want to access `abc.azurewebsites.net`. How can I prevent this redirect?

**Note:**

I changed `redirectType` to `Temporary` but it didn't worked.

I changed input `pattern` but it didn't worked.

Comment: Let me know if my question is not clear. And what else I should mention?

Comment: Commenting out the entire rule may be?

Comment: yeah I have checked by commenting the entire rule but still its redirecting.